# How should I use the RegExp to get my want in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tried about 3 hours. I face the problem about using the javascript regexp.

I have a string as below

```
var str = 'test123↵↵http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W89sMJ25nI';
```

I use the regexp to get the url match, but I also to want to get other text  except the url.

```
var match = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W89sMJ25nI';
var str = 'test123↵http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W89sMJ25nI';
var str2 = 'test123↵↵';

function checkStringContainUrl(s) {
  var re =  new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?");
  if(re.test(s)) {
    console.log("url inside");
    console.log(re.exec(s)[1] + re.exec(s)[3] + re.exec(s)[5]);

    // i also want to console 'test123↵↵'

  } else {
    console.log('no url inside');
  }
}

function checkLink(match) {
  var re = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig;
  var m = re.exec(match);
    console.log(m[1]);
}

//checkLink(match);
checkStringContainUrl(str);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vyxyLoq/)

Comment: Oh, thanks to help edit in my question.

Comment: You have to ask yourself a few questions about what the "other" text will be? Will there always be "↵" or some kind of separator in between? In which case you may use a split before performing the regexp... Can that be any text, or do you already know that it won't contain certain characters? Will it always be before the URL? etc. etc.

Comment: try this regex: /(.+)(https?:\/\/.+)/ to have an idea. Text is captured in the first set of parenthesis and the link is captured in the second set of parenthesis. Not sure why your regex is so complicated but let me know perhaps I can improve the drafted regex

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, i tried with new regexp. its ok.
But i still have question, how should i console all with ALL result ?
I updated the jsfiddle. would you like help me ?
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vyxyLoq/2/)

Comment: Can you tell us EXACTLY what result you expect for each of the examples in the Jsfiddle, this would help us help you.

Comment: @raphv Yes, I am sorry for the question not clear, first i have a string contain some url format and text, in the jsfiddle example, then i use the regexp to check the string and split it, then i want to merge sperately, the result should be 
'some text' + 'get url from regexp' + 'some text'.... etc..

Answer (score 0):

How about, once you've isolated the URL, replacing it by '' in the text?

e.g.:

```
var url = re.exec(s)[1] + re.exec(s)[3] + re.exec(s)[5]
console.log(s.replace(url,''));
```

Comment: i used the new regexp, it seems like good, but still occurs new question.